# A cleaner way to track model changes

Tags: php, laravel

The application I'm currently working on have two main user types, let's say `user` and `reviewer`. I need to create a functionality to track changes made by both `user` and `reviewer` (for `post`) and show them in the frontend. I have given specific messages to show in the frontend for each change.

ex:- `user` submits a `post`. This post must be reviewed by `reviewer`

In `user` dashboard

`Post submitted   -> Pending review`

In `reviwer` dashboard

`Pending review    -> You have a new post to review before 01/07/2019`

#### My approach

Make a language file to store all the status given.

**lang/en/status.php**

```
<?php

return [
    
    'post_accepted' => [

        'user' => [

            'from' => 'Pending review',
            'to' => 'Post accepted',

        ],

        'reviewer' => [

            'from' => 'Pending review',
            'from' => 'You have a new post to review before [DATE]',

        ]

    ]

];
```

Then I have formatted each status and saved to the database with user's id.

ex:- For `reviewer`,

```
$reviewer= $post->reviewer;

$status_from = __('status.post_accepted.reviewer.from');
$status_to = str_replace('[DATE]', '01/07/2019', __('status.post_accepted.reviewer.to'));


// Helper function for save log
add_log(
     $post,              // Post
     'post_submitted',   // unique slug for each status
     $status_from,       // from status
     $status_to,         // to status
     $reviewer->id       // reviewer id (The message should be shown to)
);
```

This is a hard approach to maintain code, not cleaner and I have to write a lot if code for each status.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this with laravel?